# What did Portugal do with the money from Brazilian independence?

Tags: independence, portugal, portuguese-empire, brazil

Brazil paid 2 million pounds sterling to Portugal as compensation for independence; this was established in the [Treaty of Rio de Janeiro (1825)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Rio_de_Janeiro_(1825)) which was mediated by Britain.

> ART. IV - There will now be peace and alliance and the most perfect friendship between the Kingdoms of Portugal and the Algarves and the Empire of Brazil with complete forgetfulness of the past disputes between the respective peoples. His Imperial Majesty pledges to pay the sum of two million pounds sterling, or 80 tons of gold, as compensation, to the Kingdoms of Portugal and the Algarves.

Are there any reliable records of what Portugal did with the money? There are claims that this money was lent to Brazil by Britain, and that the money never even left Britain, because it was used to pay debt Portugal had, but I don't know if this is true. For example of the claim, see below from [Mundo Educação](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/historiadobrasil/o-reconhecimento-independencia-brasil.htm):

> As a newly formed nation, Brazil could not pay the heavy compensation established by the 1825 treaty. At that time, the British lent the resources that ensured the payment of this amount. In fact, the money did not even leave England itself, as the Portuguese had to pay an equivalent debt to the same creditors.

Comment: Typically for a national budget, inflows are completely disjoint from outflows, so it would be more a matter of what the Government of Portugal chose to spend its money on while payments are coming in. As a US citizen I can't say that I know for a fact that my specific tax $ this year all went to fund the Federal prison at Leavenworth while my neighbors' all went to repair Interstate 40.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'll edit and make this clearer: there are claims (at least in Brazil) that this money never left England and was entirely used to pay debt to England (who lent the money to Brazil in the first place), but I don't know the veracity of these claims.

Comment: Thanks for the updates; much clearer.  If the money was to pay a debt to England, then why would be even surprising that it never left England?   It might even make sense that this would be why England mediated the claim and guaranteed the debt.

Comment: @MCW: yes, that sounds plausible and logical, however, I don't know if it's actually true. Hence the question :)

Comment: It would probably be worth investigating any outstanding debts that Portugal owned Britain following the Napoleonic Wars (during which significant sums were provided by Britain to rebuild, and maintain, the Portuguese military).

Comment: People scream "imperialism" but Britain did lend to Portugal in hours of need... and the royal family was moved to Brazil by the British navy. Similarly, people scream "gold from Minas Gerais went to England", but forget that Portugal borrowed an awful lot of $$ to expel the dutch VOC from Brazil (besides other fights in Asia). Creditors want $$$ back with interest, small fish need larger patrons to avoid being swallowed by big fish, and life is not fair.

Comment: @Luiz It was **not** the VOC. It was the [GWC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_West_India_Company)